# How can I access arrays from different threads?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pointers

I'm new to the C language. I know how threads work but I think I'm still not getting the idea how pointers works with char arrays, how to populate arrays with a loop...

The errors on the terminal are as follows...

```
q2.c: In function ‘main’:
q2.c:18:22: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
q2.c:23:57: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
q2.c:23:40: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from q2.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
q2.c: In function ‘myfunc1’:
q2.c:61:23: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ gcc q2.c -lpthread -o hell
q2.c: In function ‘main’:
q2.c:18:22: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
q2.c:23:57: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
q2.c:23:40: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from q2.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:128:14: note: expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’
q2.c: In function ‘myfunc1’:
q2.c:61:23: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

void *myfunc1(void *ptr);
void *myfunc2(void *ptr);

pthread_mutex_t lock;
char name[10];
int id[10];
int i;

int main (int argc, char argv[])
{


        memset(name, 'no' , sizeof(name));
        memset(id, 0, sizeof(id));
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                {

                                       strcpy(&name[i], 'name');

                    id[i] = i;
                }
                                //name[10] = '\0';

        pthread_t thrd1, thrd2;
        int thret1, thret2;
        char *msg1 = "First Thread";
        char *msg2 = "Second Thread";



                thret2 = pthread_create(&thrd2, NULL, myfunc2, (void *)msg2);
        thret1 = pthread_create(&thrd1, NULL, myfunc1, (void *)msg1);


        pthread_join(thrd1, NULL);
        pthread_join(thrd2, NULL);

        printf("\nthret1 = %d\n", thret1);
        printf("\nthret2 = %d\n", thret2);
        sleep(5);
        printf("Parent Thread exiting...\n");
        exit(1);

        return 0;
}

void *myfunc1(void *ptr){

        int i;
        char *msg = (char *)ptr;
        printf("\nMsg : %s\n", msg);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    printf("\n %s ", *name[i]);

                }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void *myfunc2(void *ptr){

        int i;
        char *msg = (char *)ptr;
        printf("Msg : %s\n", msg);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
                for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                {

                    printf("\n%d ", id[i]);
                }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Comment: the first thread should fill the name array with "name".. and the second thread should fill the id array with incrementing numbers...

Comment: What are you expecting `memset(name, 'no' , sizeof(name));` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are very confused between strings and characters constants.

char name[100];
char c;

A string always in "double quotes". A (single character) is enclosed in single quotes. So, "stackoverflow" is a string and 's','t','a','c','k' are characters.

Also, from a string variable, you extract individual characters using [] operator as shown below. Note that I don't use '*' operator.

```
char name[10] ;
char c;
strcpy (name,"stackoverflow");
printf ("name is %s",name);
print ("first character of name is %c", name[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `'` is for specifying characters, and `"` is specifying character strings. In

   ```
   memset(name, 'no' , sizeof(name));
   ```

   You are trying to define `'no'` which isn't allowed in c.
2. `memset` is used to set a block of memory one character value.  You might want `memcpy` or `strcpy` instead to initialize name.
3. `char name[10];` defines an array for characters, but if you want this to define an array of strings, you will need `char name[10][NAME_LEN];` instead (for whatever max value of character length).  This should also fix the `strcpy` error (don't use the the ampersand).
4. In `myfunc1`, you are dereferencing a character.  Fixing that to an array for c strings will help, but you don't need to dereference it to print it.

Comment: `'no'` *is* allowed in C but it is implementation-defined. They are called multi-character constants.